# Using bootstrap calendar inside slickgrid then Calendar is stuck issue

Tags: slickgrid

I am using bootstrap calendar inside slickgrid. When calendar popup is opened and use Alt+tab or scope out of slickgrid then calendar gets stuck. I have to reload application to get rid of calendar popup. I want to close calendar pop up as soon as user scopes out of slickgrid. Please suggest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's your problem but you can't use just a `z-index` in SlickGrid that won't work and won't do anything, you need to use `position: absolute` on your Editor (each editor has a `args.position` passed to their constructor) that you can use to reposition your editor next to the cell that you clicked, however make sure that you also add a `position()` method that will be called if it exist and of course you need to add proper code to reposition the DOM element inside that method. Also when you click on a different cell then the previous Editor will call the `destroy` method, so make sure you remove the Editor properly by adding necessary code in your `destroy()` method.

All of that position usage can be seen in 1 of the built-in Editor which is the `LongText` defined in the `slick.editors.js` on this [line](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.editors.js#L628)

The absolute style is applied [here](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.editors.js#L644)
and the `position(cellPosition)` method is defined [here](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.editors.js#L718)

If your problem is really that your Editor doesn't get removed from the DOM, then it's because you didn't code the `destroy()` properly and [here](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.editors.js#L724) is the `LongText` `destroy()` method for reference. Also you might want to add an `onBlur` event that will call your `destroy()` method after a `blur` or any other event that you choose.

and here's a print screen of the `LongText` Editor that is repositioned over the cell you clicked and you can test it yourself in this [Example - Editing](http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example3-editing.html)

[image]